# operation is not supported on this platform - problem with RSACryptoServiceProvider in dot net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Recently I have to use RSACryptoServiceProvider in dot net core 2.2.

there is something wrong with RSA.FromXmlString() inside my GetSign() method . When I call my Action from UnitTest everything is fine but when I call it from PostMan via Post Method I got below Error on **rsa.FromXmlString("XXX")**  :

> **operation is not supported on this platform**

My Unit Test:

```
[Fact]
        public void TestToken()
        {
            var contoller2 = new BankPaymentController();
            contoller2.GetToken();
       }



//My controller
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [HTTPPOST]
    public IActionResult GetToken()
    {
        BankingInputParam model2 = new BankingInputParam();
           var token = PasargadBank.CallPaymentMethod(model2);
            return Ok(token);
    }
```

This is my internal method that called inside controller

```
        //This is CallPaymentMethod
    public static string CallPaymentMethod(BankingInputParam model)
    {
        PasargadBank pasargadbank = new PasargadBank();
        var sendingData = pasargadbank.CreateTextArrayInput(model);
        var content = new StringContent(sendingData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("XXXXXXXXXX"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content
        };
        MyClass instancemyclass = new MyClass();
        var aaa = instancemyclass.GetSign(sendingData);

        request.Headers.Add("Sign", pasargadbank.GetSign(sendingData));
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;// requestMessage).Result;
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
    }
```

and this is GetSignt() method that I have problem

```
public string GetSign(string data) 
{
 var cs = new CspParameters {
  KeyContainerName = "PaymentTest"
 };
 var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cs) {
  PersistKeyInCsp = false
 };

 rsa.Clear();
 rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

 byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
 string sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
 return sign;
}
```

Comment: It means that the platform, on which you run, does not support. Where do you run it?

Comment: I Just Run it on Visual Studio debugger. This has not deployed yet.

Comment: I mean, what is a platform, not IDE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromXmlString` was not implemented fully in .NET Core until [.NET Core 3.0](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/37593).  Since .NET Core 2.2 is out of support, you should update to .NET Core 3.1 and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it ASAP and come back.

Comment: That was really the reason, Thanks!